# return custom message from API gateway lambda Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-api-gateway

I have a API gateway lambda Authorizer and when it fails it all i am getting is

```
{
   "Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"
}
```

> and the status code is 403

My lambda is written in dotnet core. The thing is i am doing something if my authentication failed and the status code should be 401 for that to happen. So just wanted to know if we have a way to customize this behavior

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your `Access Denied` response in the `Gateway Responses` section of your API Gateway.
Both response template and status code can be configured there.

If you want the response to include custom data, you can add it to the `context` map returned from your Lambda Authorizer (see [Output from an Amazon API Gateway Lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html) for more info).

This way you can customize your `Access Denied` response template, for example:

```
{
  "message": "$context.authorizer.error_message"
}
```

Obviously you can include multiple properties and return more complex responses.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Might be worth noting that we need to re-deploy the API after adding the Gateway Response template; so that another newbie like me wouldn't waste time trying to figure out why the template isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-403-error-lambda-authorizer/), that's the exact error message you will see when the Lambda authorizer function returns an IAM policy document with an explicit deny.